# Handling useEffect

Tags: react-native, use-effect

```
const UserProfile = ({
  user=[],
}) =>{ 
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted")
    console.log("inside: "+user.id)
  },[]);
  
  console.log("outside :"+user.id)
   return(
    <Text>hello</Text>
  );
};
```

Why is This returning this logs?
I think user.id in useEffect should return the same

[image: my console.log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your effect is called only once, while mounted. At the point of mounting there's no `user` value set, as you can see in logs (`outside :undefined` and `inside: undefined`). Then, when you pass `user` with `id` to `UserProfile` component, effect is not called, because registering effect with empty dependency array indicates, that it will be called only on mount.

Please check: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
(last yellow note section)

If you want your effect to be called everytime `user` property changes, add it to dependency array like below:

```
useEffect(() => {
...
},[user])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!user.id) {
    return
  }
  console.log("mounted")
  console.log("inside: "+user.id)
},[user])
```